# MODX, curl and the anonymous sessions

Tags: php, curl, modx, modx-revolution

Mainly my problem is that when I make a request with cURL including session cookie with random value the **modx session** starts with the value of that cookie.
Which is confusing me a lot.

modx session and cookie config:

```
anonymous_sessions: Yes
default_username: (anonymous)
session_cookie_httponly: Yes
session_cookie_secure: Yes
session_handler_class: [empty] 
session_name: PHPSESSID
```

Example request:

```
curl -i  -X GET "https://www.example.com/test-page" -b "PHPSESSID=adventure-time" -v
```

Request headers:

```
> GET /test-page HTTP/2
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: PHPSESSID=adventure-time
>
```

Response headers:

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 09:58:21 GMT
< server: Apache
< expires: 0
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< set-cookie: PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< content-length: 1636
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Php response:

```
$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']: adventure-time
session_id(): adventure-time
session_id() == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']: access granted
```

Isn't this wrong behaviour or I do not understand how php sessions should work? Could someone shed some light, please...

Comment: What behaviour did you expect? `PHPSESSID` allows the client to tell the server what the session id is, and that's exactly what happens. This doesn't mean that PHP accepts it lying down. Note the `set-cookie: PHPSESSID=deleted;` in the response. I don't know what your PHP code does, but the way to test a session is to see if something stored in `$_SESSION` can be retrieved. If it cannot you're no longer in the same session.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I expected some check if it exists, so basically there is no check if the session is valid based on the $_COOKIE[PHPSESSID] value? It starts new session based on it and that is it. if I loop the curl requests the sessions will be recreated.

Comment: Creating a new session is a safe option. PHP cannot guess what the session id should be, it relies on what the client tells it. There's not much to check there. If the session, for whatever reason, doesn't exist, creating one seems sensible.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, that clear my doubts, thank you

Comment: `session_id() == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']: access granted` - if that is really the check that your PHP code performs, then that is of course anything but safe. The information to determine whether the user has access, should be stored _within_ your session, not made dependent on the session ID matching the cookie.

Comment: If you want to prevent PHP from automatically _creating_ a session with whatever (fake) session ID was passed via the cookie - then you need to set [`session.use_strict_mode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) to true. Then PHP will automatically create a _new_ session ID on its own, when the passed one does not match an already existing session.

Comment: @CBroe, tempting idea that `session_id = cookie check` :) the `session.use_strict_mode` is going to help me a lot, thank you! Should read the manual more closely...